# Need details on the "reason" data found in Tracking Extract NotSent file

Tags: marketing-cloud, tracking-extract

I'm researching why several thousand of our subscriber records are not being sent emails.  I've confirmed the subscribers do not have an 'unsub' or 'held' status.  My next thought was to run a [Tracking Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5) and review the contents of the [NotSent.txt](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5) file.

The **NotSent.txt** file contains a Reason column.  But, I cannot find documentaion on all the Reason values and a definition of each.

In the Tracking Extract I ran, I see the following Reason values:

- Account Level Opt Out
- Domain Exclusion
- Excluded by Send Time Filter
- Held
- List Detective Exclusion
- List Level Opt Out
- Subscriber Deleted
- Suppression List Exclusion
- Unsubscribed
- Unsubscribed Master

Some of these I understand - like 'Held', 'Domain Exclusion' and 'Send Time Filter'.  But others I do not understand.  For example, what does 'Account Level Opt Out' means and how is it different from 'Unsubscribe' (or 'Unsubscribed_Master')

Answer (score 0):

There are [three-levels of unsubscribe](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_how_a_subscriber_opts_out.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null): list level, account level, and global.

> Account-Level Unsubscribe or Master Unsubscribe - A >subscriber who unsubscribes at the account level has an >unsubscribed status on your All Subscribers list. All current >and future lists in your account inherit the All Subscriber list.

Account level could be unsubscribed from your parent account. I don’t know how your business units are set up but you can apply unsubscribes to all business units or just that child business unit.

Typical [Salesforce Marketing Cloud documentation doesn’t list possible reasons](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5) for NotSent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another good list of [email send error codes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_email_send_error_codes.htm&type=5). It gives the error code, reason, and a brief description. You should be able to cross reference the not sent reason from the Not Sent extract with the error name description.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.